# DirectX bounding box drawing

Tags: directx, direct3d, directxtk

The idea is to draw the bounding box as 2D corners on the screen after my [DiretXTK](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK) model is displayed.

I got the bounding box corners form DirectXKT in a `std::vector<DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector3>`, so

```
auto mf = m_world * m_view * m_proj;
D3D11_VIEWPORT vp;
UINT j = 1;
ctx->RSGetViewports(&j,&vp);
for (auto& c : corners)
{
    DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector3 ft = DirectX::XMVector3Transform(c, mf);

    float scalex = vp.Width / 2;
    float scaley = vp.Height / 2;

    float screenx = ft.x * scalex;
    float screeny = ft.y * scaley;

}
```

These coordinates are invalid, something wrong I'm doing in the transforming the XYZ of each corner to the screen projection.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [DirectX Tool Kit wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/), I have a `DebugDraw` helper which is specifically designed for drawing DirectXMath bounding volumes using *DirectX Tool Kit's* `PrimitiveBatch`.

See [this topic page](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DebugDraw).

> You may also want to take a look at the [Collision](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/Collision) sample.

Comment: Worked, thanks a lot. Is that DrawRay going to help me with picking (my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67856255/direct3d-picking))?